# PHP Pagination script doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

The pagination script I use doesn't display the posts for some reason. It displays nothing, no previous link, no next link, no actual things from the mysql database. The page is not a white screen, everything else on the page works fine. It would be great if someone could help me with this.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "config.php";
if($_SESSION['usrid']){
database_connect();
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM posts limit '.($page*$eachPage).','.$eachPage;

$sql_count = 'SELECT id FROM posts';
                if(isset($_GET['page']) AND ctype_digit($_GET['page'])) {

    $page = $_GET['page'];    
}
else{

    $page = 0;    
}

if(!$res = mysql_query($sql)) {

  trigger_error(mysql_error().'<br />In query: '.$sql); 
} 
elseif(mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) { 

  echo 'No posts found'; 
} 
else { 

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
  $posttime = date("F j \a\t g:i a", strtotime ( $row [ 'time' ] ));
      ?>
      <div class="t"><p id="i"><?php echo $row['post']; ?><br /><b class="oinf">By <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="od"> on <?php echo $posttime; ?></a></b></p></div><br /><br />
    <?php
  }

  if($res = mysql_query($sql_count)) {

      $results = mysql_num_rows($res);
    }
  $pages = ceil($results / $eachPage);

  if($page > 0) {

      echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($page-1).'">[Previous]</a>';
  }
  else{

      echo '[Previous]';
  }

  for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++)    {

      echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($i-1).'">'.$i.'</a>';
    } 

  if(($page+1) <= ($results/$eachPage)) {

      echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($page+1).'">[Next]</a>';
  }
  else{

      echo '[Next]';
  }
}

            }else{

            };?>
```

Edit: I know tried to use this code for debugging, but it gives me the same result as above, it does not display the posts:

```
if($_SESSION['usrid']){
    database_connect();
    $navquery = "SELECT * from posts";
$navresult = mysql_query($navquery) or die(mysql_error());  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($navresult)) {
    ?>
    <div class="t"><p id="i"><?php echo $row['post']; ?><br /><b class="oinf">By <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="od"> on <?php echo $row['time']; ?></a></b></p></div><br /><br />
    <?php
};
};
```

Comment: This is **awful**:`<script type="javascscript">window.location = "index.php"</script>`. You should be using HTTP redirects via [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: By "it displays nothing" do you mean you get a blank white screen?

Comment: Ok, I changed that, but that won't help me with my problem. Thanks though.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja: no, I mean that it won't display what I want it to display. Everything else on the page is displayed and works as I want it to.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful error description. Please do some debugging first, and try to isolate the problem to a smaller chunk of code.

Comment: I changed the question so that only the pagination code shows. I also restated my question a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, I forgot a `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Echo out this SQL query and find out why your script isn't working.

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM posts limit '.($page*$eachPage).','.$eachPage;
```

Returns:

```
SELECT id FROM posts limit ,
```

Since `$page` and `$eachPage` are not defined. Are those supposed to come from `$_GET`? Because someone could actually just do this:

```
/mypage?page=0&eachPage=;DELETE FROM posts;
```

And you're not doing anything to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Please see my answer, and I decided not to use this pagination script anymore.